# What is the circle showing on android call screen?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, android-versions

[image]

What is showing on this circle in middle?

Comment: My guess is some sort of Caller ID Picture, Sometimes they're taken from Facebook profile pictures or Google Hangouts profile picture's depending on your settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spot is for the contact's picture. If you have no specific picture saved for the contact, then the system will show this default dummy picture.
Or in other case, if this picture is different from the default contact picture, then there's some picture added for this contact. Check the contact to see if it has an associated picture.